# How to use Auth in cakephp using mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a mongo db structure for users with "username" and "password". I am trying to use the Auth in cakephp login but it seems like its not working for me. I tried removing the $this->data but still it did not work.

My password is hashed using Security::hash($this->data['User']['password'])

```
if(!empty($this->data))
{
   if($this->Auth->login($this->data))
   {
       echo "yes";
   }
   else{
       echo "no";
   }
}
```

In my app controller I have this:

```
public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar', 'Session', 'Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array(
        'controller' => 'pages',
        'action' => 'home'
    ),
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password')
        )
    )
));
```

Here is the result when I debug the login method:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'username' => 'test@test.com',
        'remember' => '0',
        'auto_login' => '0'
)
)
```

I don't know why I cannot use Auth with mongodb. Thanks for the help in advance.

EDIT:

When i tried and take away the layout, it shows me a query at the bottom of the page saying:

```
db.users.find( {"username":"test@test.com","password":"2fdf49ffc396453960802df8fc2417655d1e8fca"}, [] ).sort( [] ).limit( 1 ).skip( 0 )
```

The hashed value of the password that I inputted from the form is different from the hash value that is being queried. The hashed value should be "a2374c309ab7823dcd9b4e21dae7511f7a9c7ec5". Why is it that cakephp is converting the password into another hash value?

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: In that case you should be using `$this->request->data` instead of `$this->data`.

Comment: I already tried that. When I did that, even if my password or username is wrong, it would always output "yes".

Comment: Can you try adding `debug($this->request->data);` at the start of the login method and posting the result? It might help.

Comment: hi @xgalvin I modified the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of using `$this->Auth->login()`. The CakePHP API [documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-AuthComponent.html#_login) explains it:

> If a $user is provided that data will be stored as the logged in user. If $user is empty or not specified, the request will be used to identify a user.

The [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in) also mentions:

> In 2.0 $this->Auth->login($this->request->data) will log the user in with whatever data is posted ...

So for the login method of the users controller you shouldn't pass anything:

```
if($this->Auth->login()) {
    // user is now logged in
}
```

Should you need to manually login a user you can pass the user data as an array:

```
if($this->Auth->login($this->request->data['User'])) {
    // user is now logged in
}
```

Where `$this->request->data['User']` is something like:

```
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => '1234',
);
```

**Note:** In both cases you don't need to hash the password as it is done automatically.

Comment: hi @xgalvin thanks for your reply. Here's my problem, if I add a parameter in the $this->Auth->login(), I always get a "yes", but if I dont add a parameter, I always get a no.

Comment: When you pass a parameter you are forcing the login. If login is failing when you don't it's due to an authentication error. Are you checking `$this->Session->flash('auth');` somewhere in your view?

Comment: Hi @xgalvin, I updated my question. Cake is converting my password into a different type of hash that's why its not authenticating. Can you tell me why its like this? Thanks

Comment: Convention over configuration! I think you can change the default hashing method in the authentication components configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find out the answer. Its because cakephp is automatically hashing the password when searching in the database.

The problem that I had was when I was saving the users' password, I am was using

```
Security::hash($this->data['User']['password'])
```

I should have used this one instead:

```
AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password'])
```

Thank you for all the help especially to @xgalvin